# Como usar plugin jquery no vuejs2

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Estou enfrentado dificuldade na hora de setar configurações para o  componente que utiliza jquery no vuejs2.

```
<div id="app">
        <date-picker @update-date="updateDate" timepicker= "false" v-once></date-picker>
        <p>{{ date }}</p>
 </div>

<script>

Vue.component('date-picker', {
    template: '<input/>',
    props: [ 'timepicker' ],
    mounted: function() {
    var self = this;
    $(this.$el).datetimepicker({
      timepicker: this.timepicker,

      onSelect: function(date) {
        self.$emit('update-date', date);
      }
    });
    },
    beforeDestroy: function() {
      $(this.$el).datetimepicker('hide').datetimepicker('destroy');
    }
  });

  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      date: null
    },
    methods: {
      updateDate: function(date) {
        this.date = date;
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Opção #1: Usar ProvidePlugin**

Adicione o [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin) no array de plugins nos arquivos `build/webpack.dev.conf.js` e `build/webpack.prod.conf.js`, assim o jQuery se torna global para todos os seus módulos:

```
plugins: [

  // ...

  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
]
```

**Opção #2: Usar *Expose Loader module for webpack***

Adicione o pacote [Expose Loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expose-loader):

```
npm install expose-loader --save-dev
```

Use no entry point do seu `main.js` da seguinte forma:

```
import 'expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery'

// ...
```